# Load jQuery after ExtJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs

Disclaimer: ExtJS - intermediate level;
            jQuery - beginner

I've looked for a solution for this but had not found anything yet.

I have both ExtJS and jQuery in one file and I want to be able to execute the jQuery right after the ExtJS is done building a page (is this even possible).

Example:

```
function renderPage(){
// ExtJS goes here
}
```

How do I call jQuery after renderPage() is completed?

I tried the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");
});

$(document).ready(function(renderPage) {
    $("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");
});

function renderPage(){
// ExtJS goes here
// ...

   $("tr").css("background-color", "yellow");
}
```

but it doesn't work. I assume it is because the ExtJS is not done rendering the page when jQuery is getting called and it is not finding anything to select.

Additional information:

I know my jQuery works and is connected to the library because I was able to select HTML elements that are rendered before any script ExtJS or jQuery script is run and modify their style.

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Ext code running asynchronously? How are you determining it's "not done rendering"?

Comment: It's my guess as to why the jQuery is not selecting the elements. I do not really know why it is not selecting. I am thinking that document.ready() triggers when all the html is done loading but at the same time that is when ExtJS starts rendering so I'm assuming jQuery tries to select while ExtJS is rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ext components fire an `afterrender` event that you can hook into, but you have to be careful here because it can fire more than once if you render more than once (which is easy to do accidentally). This is an example of a simple app that fires `afterrender` once for a panel.

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        var panel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel',{
            renderTo:Ext.getBody(),
            title:'myPanel',
            items: [
                Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
                    text: 'Click me!!!!',
                    handler: function() {
                        alert('You clicked the button!');
                    }
                }),
                {
                    xtype:'toolbar',
                    items: [{text:'Button 1'}, {text:'Button 2'}],
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function () {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Fiddle', 'done with ext rendering, do jQuery stuff');
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        });
    }
});
```

sencha fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/eqg

I would recommend not mixing these two libraries without a really good reason - Ext has virtually the same DOM helper functionality as jQuery - if you are just changing a class something like Ext.dom.Element.addCls might be more appropriate (http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element)

Comment: Thanks this worked. I know that most of the functionality is already present in ExtJS. I would only use jQuery for some problems that easier to solve using jQuery than ExtJS. Basically I just want to have more flexibility if I ever need it. ExtJS will be the main library I use.

Comment: And for class change in ExtJS one can use the 'cls' config for a component.